# Export into pdf a moderncv org-mode file (MacTex)

Tags: mactex, org-mode

I try to export a org file into pdf file with `moderncv` as document class.

I am on OSX, installed last version of MacTeX (2017 distribution, the full one) and I have currently no problem to export a very-basic org file (no headers or options).

I did zero configuration on org-mode and when I try to export this file :

```
  #+LaTeX_CLASS: moderncv

  * My life
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
```

My Emacs mini-buffer says : `Unkown LaTeX class 'moderncv'`

The package `moderncv` is installed on my computer as the Tex Live Utility reports and I succeeded to compile the template.tex example from moderncv doc with `pdflatex`.

What can I miss ? Do I have to set env variables or org-mode variables ?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Thanks ! I am really newbie to Latex (but I know better org-mode, that's why I like to remains in the org context). Hope someone can help me ! Best regards

Answer (score 4):

The classes accepted by org-mode LaTeX export are defined in the customize variable `org-latex-classes`. You can either use `customize-variable` or add an entry in your `.emacs` file like the following (see also [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/896741/how-do-i-configure-org-latex-classes-in-emacs#1106691))

```
(with-eval-after-load 'ox-latex
   (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
            '("moderncv"
              "\\documentclass{moderncv}"
              ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
              ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}"))))
```

EDIT: For the template to work, you should also add some options to your org-file, i.e. switching off the generation of a table of contents (which `moderncv` does not know) and inserting your first and last name:

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS: moderncv
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \firstname{Max}\lastname{Mustermann}
```

Also, you may need to switch of the `hyperref` package by setting it to `nil` in `org-latex-default-packages-alist`.